# Prevent cypress type() from firing pointer/mouse events

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, cypress, integration-testing

Testing more complex behavior of user input involving keys with Cypress got me stuck. The app uses hotkeys to trigger operational modes and cannot afford to let random mouse/pointer events get fired whenever a key is pressed. One supposed scenario is

- hold down alt key
- draw a polygon
- release alt key

Using `cy.type` results in the first two steps registering as a double click, performing an unwanted action. Release key action results in one more point (screen middle) being added to the polygon.

I tried many varians of `type()` call, tried replacing it with `trigger()` (did not even fire) with and without `focus()` combination such as

```
cy.get(selector)
    .trigger('keydown', { eventConstructor: 'KeyboardEvent', key: key, release: false })
    .trigger('keypress', { eventConstructor: 'KeyboardEvent', key: key, release: false })
```

tried *real cypress events* plugin (which seem not to support key press without a release action).

How would you fire just a simple `KeyboardEvent` event without all the mess around?

[image: Typing fires too many actions - the command log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have fine control over the events sent, use plain JS [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```js
cy.get(selector).then($el => {
  $el[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'a'}))
})
```

The fact that `trigger()` didn't work indicates you haven't identified the correct event or target, it should work the same way as `dispatchEvent()`.

Since you're drawing, maybe you should be looking at mouse events instead of keyboard events (unless the app is supposed to draw using the keyboard).

Comment: _The app uses hotkeys to trigger operational modes_ - keys are used to switch between drawing modes. It's a medicine software where you need by default navigation and quickly switch to annotation creation. I was hoping for some `type` options that disable the mouse events, I will try jQuery.

Comment: It worked in the end, you also were right that I did not use trigger on the correct node, somehow I hoped when `type` works `trigger` will too which is probably not the case... I would still prefer some `type` version since it has better interface, but this will have to suffice. Thanks.